# Compare two dictionaries with list of values which satisfies multiple conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to compare two dictionaries that have list of values as follows:

```
dict1 = {'111': [], '333': ['a@a.com'], '444': ['b@b.com', 'c@c.com'], '555': ['d@d.com']}
dict2 = {'111': ['e@e.com'], '333': ['f@f.com' ], '444': ['b@b.com', 'g@g.com'], '555': ['d@d.com']}
```

and create a resultant dict (result_dict) that satisfies the following conditions:

1. dict2 values that are not present in dict1 for the specific key add to result_dict
2. if values for dict1 and dict2 are the same then that key need not be added in result_dict(For eg 555 should be skipped)

The resultant dict should look as follows:

```
   dict3 = {'1111': ['e@e.com'], '333': ['f@f.com'], '444': ['g@g.com']}
```

I have the following code

```
    result_dict = {}
    for k,v in dict2.items():
        for k1,v1 in dict1.items():
            if k == k1 and v != v1:
               result_dict[k] = v


    print(result_dict)
```

Which outputs :

```
{'111': ['e@e.com'], '333': ['f@f.com'], '444': ['b@b.com', 'g@g.com']}
```

In the above case it should not have added `'b@b.com'` for 444. It also gives incorrect result if the order is changed for eg

```
'444': ['b@b.com', 'c@c.com']
'444': ['c@c.com', 'b@b.com']
```

Sorting dict values will not help, coz there will be scenarios where dict1 has more values than dict2 for ceratin keys. I am using Python 3.7. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep the same order in the `result_dict` as in the original dict (`dict2`, I mean):

```py
result_dict = {
    k: v if k not in dict1 else [a for a in v if a not in dict1[k]]
    for k, v in filter(lambda x: len(set(x[1]).difference(dict1.get(x[0], []))), dict2.items())
}
```

Here `result_dict`:

```sh
{'111': ['e@e.com'], '333': ['f@f.com'], '444': ['g@g.com']}
```

The output dict is created by a [dict comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/). Basically, we select keys in `dict2` whose values are lists with at least one original element compared to the correspondent lists in `dict1`. Then, lists of the selected keys are cleaned, removing elements also present in the correspondent lists in `dict1`. In particular:

- `filter(lambda x: len(set(x[1]).difference(dict1.get(x[0], []))), dict2.items()) }`: only loop over the pairs key/list of `dict2` having at least one element that is not in the correspondent list of `dict1`.
- `k: v if k not in dict1 else [a for a in v if a not in dict1[k]]` create an entry in the new dict with the same key of `dict2` and as value the corresponding list in `dict2`, if the key in not in `dict1`, else create a new list (with [list comprehension](https://realpython.com/list-comprehension-python/#using-list-comprehensions)) looping over the item in the list of `dict2` and removing those also in the correspondent list in `dict1` (this will preserve the order of the original list in `dict2`.

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: can you please explain what is going on here it looks very dense @PieCot

Comment: @AjayMisra I've updated the answer. Not be afraid to ask if it is not clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out any of the items who's values match, then within a dict comprehension the new keys should be the `set.difference` for the corresponding keys.

```
>>> {k:list(set(v).difference(dict1[k])) for k,v in dict2.items() if dict1[k] != v}
{'111': ['e@e.com'], '333': ['f@f.com'], '444': ['g@g.com']}
```